# Array exporting to csv from powershell stack issue

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, vmware, powercli

I am creating a reporting script in powercli for our vSphere.
I am trying to make an array that i can export to csv.
The problem i am having is i need to have multiple rows to input into the array, not just the same one over and over.

When i run in current format all that happens is the outermost row reports and none of the internal ones

Here is a mockup of what i want the script to do.

```
$report = @()
foreach($D in $data){
$row = "" | select Datacenter, datacenterInfo
$row.datacenter = "kam1"
$row.datacenterInfo = "12"
$report += $row
foreach($F in $D){
    $row2 = "" | select folder, folderInfo
    $row2.folder = "test"
    $row2.folderInfo = "34"
    $report += $row2
    foreach($VM in $F){
        $row3 = "" | select VM, VMInfo
        $row3.VM = "test"
        $row3.VMInfo = "56"
                    $report += $row3
    }
}
}

$report | export-csv -path c:\temp\testy.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any Help Appreciated

data would hopefully come out as a csv in excel while looking like so

```
datacenter / datacenterinfo
test       / 12
folder     /  folderinfo
test       / 34
VM         / VMInfo
test       / 56
```

The real script would be detailing hundreds of VM's and folder though.

Comment: Can you show the output you expect to get from that set of data?

Comment: How are the Folder|FolderInfo and VM|VMInof properties supposed to be presented in the CSV?  It can only have one set of column headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this problem and have no real Solution for it. 
But as workaround you could use 
`"$row3.VM \ $row3.VMInfo" | Out-File -append -path "c:\temp\testy.csv"`
in your inner for each, and write the data manually as csv.

Comment: I ended up working around it by putting all the variables into a single super row and only populating what i needed